# LIve search recommended products and auto search form not showing including tax price Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6, adobe-commerce, adobe-sensei, liveseach

Magento 2.4.6 Live search set price to show included tax in catalog but **price not display included tax in header auto search and adobe sensei recommend products**.

[image]

Magento version :- Adobe Commerce ver. 2.4.6-p1 with **Live Search**.

Thank you,